# Calculate number of transaction per hour using batch file

Tags: batch-file

My log is in a text file format which looks something like this

```
UID,      Provider,     MobileNo,      Result Time,        Outcome
443,        ABC,        65437261,   2016-08-09 23:59:59,     Pass
445,        ABC,        87658905,   2016-08-09 23:58:05,     Pass
023,        ABC,        87658905,   2016-08-09 21:58:05,     Pass
023,        ABC,        87658905,   2016-08-09 19:58:05,     Pass
```

I would like to know how do I create a batch file that reads the file and calculate the number of transaction per hour.

I would like my outcome to be as follows:

```
2300Hrs 345 transactions
2200Hrs 2891 transactions
0700Hrs 8873 transactions
```

Comment: what have you tried? ATM this is too broad and hard to figure out what you want.

Comment: A little more detail about your requirements would help as well as an example of what you want your output to look like.

Comment: Open Notepad (or another plain text editor), type in suitable commands and save the file with `.bat` or `.cmd` extension.

Comment: Maybe your output example should represent your input example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand your request ("transaction per hour" is a *speed term*). However, if you want to *count* the number of *lines* in the file that have *the same hour*, then this is a solution:

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem Count transactions in the same hour
for /F "skip=1 tokens=5 delims=: " %%a in (theLogFile.txt) do set /A "trans[%%a]+=1"

rem Report them
for /F "tokens=2,3 delims=[]=" %%a in ('set trans[') do echo %%a00Hrs %%b transactions
```

Output example with the given data:

```
1900Hrs 1 transactions
2100Hrs 1 transactions
2300Hrs 2 transactions
```

Answer (score 0):

…As a continuation of the excellent response by @Aacini, and to pre-empt the inevitable spaces in the Provider and/or MobileNo fields, perhaps:

```
@Echo Off
SetLocal

Rem Count transactions in the same hour
For /F "Skip=1 Tokens=4 Delims=," %%a In (theLogFile.txt) Do (Set _=%%a
    Call Set/A "trans[%%_:~-8,2%%]+=1")

Rem Report them
For /F "Tokens=2,3 Delims=[]=" %%a In ('Set trans[') Do (
    Echo( %%a00Hrs %%b transaction(s^))
Timeout -1
```